# float.TryParse ignores decimal point

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using visual studio code on windows, creating mvc app using latest asp.net core.

when I run this code:

```
string number = "13,89";
float convertedNumber = -1f;
bool result = float.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out convertedNumber);
```

I get result = true, indicating that parsing was successful, but actual convertedNumber = 1389;

I tried different cultures, different numberstyles and I just don't get it. I would understand getting result = false, but not this. and I have no idea how to fix it.

c# fiddle for convenience: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ZDwis

Comment: `,` is a *thousand separator*, not a *decimal point* in case of *invariant culture*. If you put a specific culture, say, russian: `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU")` you'll have `,` as decimal separator (and `.` will thousand separator)

Comment: *"I tried different cultures"* did you try any that use `,` as a decimal point?

Comment: Is your question actually: Why does it not fail?

Comment: interestingly though thats not a valid string with , as the thousands separator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`,` is interpreted as a thousand separator, not a decimal point. For example, this will work:

```
string number = "13.89";
```

Or alternatively, use a culture where the comma is used as a decimal, for example French:

```
string number = "13,89";
float convertedNumber = -1f;
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
bool result = float.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Any, culture, out convertedNumber);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want `float.TryParse` to treat the `,` as a decimal separator instead of a thousand separator, you should use a culture that has the comma as decimal separator, like Dutch:

```
bool result = float.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("nl-nl"), out converted);
```